# Como exibir o resultado de um Inner Join para o usuário?

Tags: banco-de-dados, wordpress, inner, sqlfiddle

Tenho três tabelas e quero juntá-las e exibi-las para o usuário, como posso fazer isso utilizando as funções do WordPress?

INSERE OS DADOS NO BANCO:

```
function cadastra_experiencia($nome, $email, $experiencia){          //INSERE OS DADOS NO BANCO
     global $wpdb;

    $table = 'experiencia';

    $data = array(
      'nome' => $nome,
      'email' => $email,
      'exp' => $experiencia,
    );

    $updated = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );

    if ( ! $updated ) {
      $wpbb->print_error();
    }
}

function cadastra_alturapesotipo($altura, $peso, $estilo){
//INSERE OS DADOS NO BANCO
     global $wpdb;

    $table = 'alturapesoestilo';

    $data = array(
      'altura' => $altura,
      'peso' => $peso,
      'estilo' => $estilo,
    );

    $updated = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );

    if ( ! $updated ) {
      $wpbb->print_error();
    }
}
```

BANCO:

```
CREATE TABLE EXPERIENCIA(
     exp_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     nome VARCHAR(150),
     email VARCHAR(50),
     exp VARCHAR(100),
     PRIMARY KEY(exp_pri)
);

CREATE TABLE PRANCHA(
    prancha_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tamanho_prancha VARCHAR(8),
    meio_prancha VARCHAR(2),
    litragem_prancha VARCHAR(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (prancha_pri)
);

CREATE TABLE ALTURAPESOESTILO(
    idAltPes INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idExp INT,
    idPrancha INT,
    altura VARCHAR(4),
    peso VARCHAR(3),
    estilo VARCHAR(15),
    primary key (idAltPes),
    constraint fk_idExp foreign key (idExp) references EXPERIENCIA (exp_pri),
    constraint fk_idPrancha foreign key (idPrancha) references PRANCHA (prancha_pri)
 );
```

INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT EXP.exp,
       AEP.altura,
       AEP.peso,
       AEP.estilo,
       PRAN.tamanho_prancha,
       PRAN.meio_prancha,
       PRAN.litragem_prancha
FROM EXPERIENCIA AS EXP
    INNER JOIN ALTURAPESOESTILO AS AEP ON
    (EXP.exp_pri = AEP.idAltPes)
    INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN ON
    (PRAN.prancha_pri = AEP.idAltPes)
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle para ter uma melhor visualização: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5eb8a/3

Eu quero exibir este `inner join` para o usuário (texto, alert, modal), qualquer exemplo/caminho de como fazer isso é bem vindo.

Dei uma olhada no Codex do WordPress, mas sem muito sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando `$wpdb->insert`,não sei se você sabe mas a classe `wpdb` é fácil de se injetar um ataque ao SQL,pois ele interpreta algumas funções de sua própria classe como input,e pode acabar danificando o seu banco de dados.

Para melhor entendimento,leia a documentação do Wordpress sobre o assunto :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Agora falando sobre o seu problema,já tentou usar `fetchAll()`? Ele retorna uma array contendo todas as linhas do conjunto de resultados e para inner join isto funciona perfeitamente.

Existem duas funções relacionadas a buscar linhas de resultados. O `fetchAll()` obtém todas as linhas de uma só vez. E o `fetch()` obtém linha por linha a cada chamada.

Mas creio que você irá usar a função `fetchAll()` para obter todos os resultados de uma vez,pois é mais conveniente quando se trabalha com `inner joins`.

Dê uma olhada na documentação dele.Com este comando você pode executar de forma bem fácil e mostrar o resultado ao usuário.

Documentação do fetchAll(): http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php.

Documentação do fetch() : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php